# Windows : How can auto proxy setup be retrieved?

Tags: winapi, proxy, windows-10

I'm wondering how I can retrieve the host's current Proxy Settings using Windows SDK function(s) ?

In Windows 10 these settings look like this:

[image]

I'm particularly interested in retrieving the information in the red box above. I'm familiar with the WinHTTP API but that will only retrieve information from the bottom part of the above window (the Manual Proxy section).

I've figured out where the information in the red box is stored in the Registry, but I don't think Microsoft intends us to go that route as the other information about Proxy is indeed available via SDK functions which shields the caller from knowing where the information is actually stored. I'm sure it is there somewhere in the SDK.

I'm looking for a solution which can even be called from a headless process, e.g. a service. As far as I understand this then excludes using the WinInet API.

Comment: Isn't this a per-user configuration setting? In that case, you cannot (easily) retrieve that information from a service.

Comment: @IInspectable. At the end of the day everything is in the Registry, somewhere. But lets assume the admin has put proxy config into HKLM, not HKCU. (On Win10 this would be `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` as opposed to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [KB226473](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/226473/how-to-programmatically-query-and-set-proxy-settings-under-internet-ex) IE4 used `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` ([`INTERNET_PROXY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385148(v=vs.85).aspx)) and it only provides the basic proxy info. IE5+ uses `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` ([`INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385146(v=vs.85).aspx)) to get/set proxy options. Pass `NULL` as the handle to `InternetQueryOption` to read the global options.

The options are usually user specific but can be forced to HKLM by the ProxySettingsPerUser REG_DWORD setting. I believe WinINet just uses normal registry functions to read the settings so you could perhaps try to call `RegDisablePredefinedCache` and impersonate the user. `RegOverridePredefKey` might also work.

This implies that you know which user is the "correct" user.